# Problem in generating bar graph from google chart from database extracted values?

Tags: php, mysql, react-google-charts

**My database table (test_12) is as follows:**

```
S.I                   A              B               C              X        Y                        
SBI234      2.280130800000  2.339592225000  2.237112614000  2.296371308000  2.295634019000  
SBI316      1.832411563000  1.825578753000  1.830375097000  1.826226610000  1.831125007000  
SBI425      1.922666139000  1.937724567000  1.913369116000  1.941975395000  1.937476796000  
SBI567      1.926532891000  1.956353519000  1.978980200000  1.982052669000  2.001432287000
```

**My Code used to draw bar graph (Google chart) is as follows:**

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root123","myDB");
if ($con) {
    echo "connected";
    }
?>  
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['S.I','A','B','C','X','Y']
         <?php
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM test_12";
         $fire = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
         while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($fire)){
             echo"['".$result['S.I']."',".$result['A'].",".$result['B'].", ".$result['C'].",".$result['X'].",".$result['Y']."]";
             }
          ?>
         ]);

     var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Google_Chart_Test',
            subtitle: 'Bar graph test',
          }
        };
           var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The Result i am getting is attached kindly help me to solve the problem.
Database connection is showing, graph shows null values on all axis.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W4tf.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at your output code. It's invalid; missing commas at the very least, and possibly quote marks. Your browser's Javascript console is certainly shouting errors at you. And do you really have a database column called "S.I"? Unlikely or unwise.

Comment: Thanks, miken32 for reply. I don't find any missing commas in my script. As I also checked for syntax error which shows no error. Further database column called S.I in question is actually "name" for simplicity in question i changed it to S.I.  Does the problem is because of the type of data, I'm not able to figure it out. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Similar question, related to google chart, do not solve my problem. So please open this question.

Comment: ANYONE KNOW THE SOLUTION PLEASE REPLY !